# Delaunay triangulation and voronoi diagram in 3d space

Tags: geometry, mesh, triangulation, tetrahedra

I was looking for information about algorithms for constructing Delaunay triangulation (tetrahedralisation) and Voronoi diagrams, but there is quite little information (or I'm bad at looking for information). What effective algorithms exist to build these structures? Are there methods that can be paralleled?

Comment: There are lots of info out there. Start with: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/jrspapers.html#cd  and then https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925772196000259 and even https://www.academia.edu/16233808/Design_and_Implementation_of_a_Practical_Parallel_Delaunay_Algorithm

Answer (score 1):

3D Delaunay Tetrahedralization of random input points in Unity.Voronoi Diagram is generated in real time with Jump Flooding Algorithm (HLSL compute shader). Source code: https://github.com/przemyslawzaworski/Unity-GPU-Based-Tetrahedralization